# Adding a gist in Yarn

Tags: yarnpkg

I can `yarn add` a git repo. Is there a standard/best-practice way to do the same for gists?

If I run `yarn add https://gist.github.com/tiernan/c18a380935e45a6d942ac1e88c5bbaf3` this saves `serviceworker.d.ts` under `node_modules/c18a380935e45a6d942ac1e88c5bbaf3/serviceworker.d.ts`, which makes it very hard to reference. Is there any way I can `yarn add` this file to a more useful place? Ideally `node_modules/@types/serviceworker/index.d.ts`.

Or is it better to just manually copy+paste gists to a separate folder in my project?

Comment: I've had some luck with aliasing, `yarn add @types/serviceworker@https://gist.github.com/c18a380935e45a6d942ac1e88c5bbaf3.git` will put the file under `node_modules/@types/serviceworker/serviceworker.d.ts`. Not quite what I want, but it works okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `package.json` to your gist with the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "@types/serviceworker",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

After that adding your gist via:
`yarn add https://gist.github.com/tiernan/c18a380935e45a6d942ac1e88c5bbaf3.git`
will automatically add it as `@types/serviceworker` dependency

Comment: Good suggestion, but the gist isn't mine so I can't add a `package.json`.

I could maintain my own version of the gist, but then it would be similar to just keeping it in a `/dependencies` folder in my project